# android ViewPager setOnLongClickListener event not working

Tags: android, events, android-viewpager

In one of my application i need ***ViewPager*** in that loading images from ***URL***... this working good....
Now i want to do is:
1] save that image to **sdcard**... ***onlong click***

But i am not able to fire on click event
i have done...

1] In ***instantiateItem*** method of ***PagerAdapter***

```
((ViewPager) container).setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("this is done!!");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

2] i have also tried to use image vies long clik event but that also not working

and 3] and also done like this

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    System.out.println("test");
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

But none of the above way i am solving my problem of long click get cleared..

Answer (score -2):

just change `new OnLongClickListener()` with `new View.OnLongClickListener()`

Comment: No. See [ViewPager and longclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554450/viewpager-and-longclick) or [ViewPager OnLongClick listener not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122328/viewpager-onlongclick-listener-not-firing).